# Enabling implicit type checking for Javascript in VS Code results in "Cannot find name 'require'" error

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I made a very simple Node project (`npm init`, accept all defaults) and opened it in VS Code.  I followed [the instructions in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files) to turn on global implicit type checking: set `javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs` to `true` in user prefs.

Now, when I try to use `require()` in the code, I get a red squiggly underline with the error `[js] Cannot find name 'require'.`  Do I need to do something to tell the Typescript server that this will run in a Node environment, and thus `require` will be provided as a global?

ETA: I'm not totally clear on the disconnect between whatever is generating the "Cannot find name" error, and whatever is creating Intellisense suggestions.  In spite of the `require()` error, Intellisense works correctly.  If I `npm install --save moment`, then write

```
const moment = require("moment");
moment.
```

then I get Intellisense completion of Moment functions, even though `require` has a red squiggly line under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to install node typing via
`npm install --save-dev @types/node`
This will install node types locally.

Comment: This got rid of the squigglies but I feel like it should be automated.  Is there maybe a setting (`tsconfig.json` or similar) that would make VSCode take care of this automatically?  I really don't know much about Typescript.

Comment: I guess you can install the types globally. However I find in most cases its better to have types versioned locally as a project specific dependency.