# Visual Studio Code - TypeScript type checking - recognize external objects in JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Have enabled TypeScript checking in a JavaScript-only project in VS Code using the global setting

> "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true

The type checking works, but for every external/global variable it shows a 'cannot find name' error:

> $('body').addClass('something'); // cannot find name '$'
>
> MyCustomObject.doSomething(); // cannot find name 'MyCustomObject'

How can I make VS Code recognize these global variables ?  I think that this needs to be done using a custom definition file specified in a jsconfig.json, but haven't been able to make it work.

UPDATE:

Not a duplicate of [Enabling implicit type checking for Javascript in VS Code results in "Cannot find name 'require'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347599).

Have seen that ticket and it is related only to a node.js project and the accepted answer is related to installing the type definition npm package for nodejs. Which is not the case here. I need to set up a custom defintion file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling implicit type checking for Javascript in VS Code results in "Cannot find name 'require'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347599/enabling-implicit-type-checking-for-javascript-in-vs-code-results-in-cannot-fin)

Comment: Maybe the [discussion here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626) is of relevance.

Comment: @zgue don't think it's a duplicate. Have seen that ticket and it is related only to a node.js project and the accepted answer is related to installing the type definition npm package for nodejs. Which is not the case here. I need to set up a custom defintion file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare global types as shown in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html

Keep the declared types as `any` so that tsc doesn't complain about not being a function or not having properties.

Create an index.d.ts file in the root folder with content

```
declare global {
    var $: any;
    var MyCustomObject: any;
}
export {};
```

After changing the index.d.ts file restart VSCode to make it recognize the types.

Comment: Thanks, have created an index.d.ts file in the root folder with content

`declare global {  var $: any;  var MyCustomObject: any; } export {};`

After changing the index.d.ts file, I had to restart VSCode to make it recognize the types

Comment: can you add my comment to your answer to have the code snippet properly formatted ? I will accept your answer after that

Comment: Thank you for this! Been searching for it for ages!